# JQuery, Selecting every img in the n'th div with a specific class

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Something like

```
$('.mydiv' :eq(n) 'img')
```

but yeah that is a terrible way of writing it ah, help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show how it works with variable n:

```
$('.mydiv:eq('+n+') img')
```

You use + operator to concat in JavaScript.

Answer (score 2):

You're almost there:

```
// Select all img elements in the 1st .mydiv:
$('.mydiv:eq(0) img')

// Select all img elements in the 3rd .mydiv:
$('.mydiv:eq(2) img')
```

See more examples of `:eq()` at http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector.

---

To use a variable inside `:eq`, do the following

```
// Select all img elements in the `n`th .mydiv:
$('.mydiv:eq('+n+') img')
```

Comment: Thanks Andy! How would I make that number inside `eq()` a variable?

Answer (score 1):

```
$("div.myclass:eq(n) img")
```